# Define automatically (loop) all statements in class definition (python)

Tags: python, class, statements

For storing some tabulated data, my system requires declaring a class. No way around it as it is build this way and I have no control on changing this.

The thing is that my tabulated data have a large number of columns, all of the same type. I should follow the following structure:

```py
class ClassName:
    <statement-1>
    .
    .
    .
    <statement-N>
```

My question now is, is there a way to define in a loop these statements? Since they are all the same (one for each column, all column type is the same), or I am forced to write manually the statements for each individual column?

Did not try anything because I don't know how to proceed. The only way I would approach the problem is to brute force the class definition (write all individual statements).

```py
class ClassName:
    columnA: type
    .
    .
    .
    columnZZZ: type
```

Comment: You can do that with the three-argument version of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Something like `type('Foo', (), {'stmt1': 'bar', ...})`. Where the dict can be created programmatically.

Comment: What *are* these statements? Are they really all just type annotations? (And if they are, what's using the annotations? Yes, it matters.)

Comment: Yes, just spark type annotations. What is using these annotations I don't know/can't say

Comment: @deceze `type` won't help with `__annotations__`

Comment: I see three major options: write manually, write a codegen (using ast or just jinja templates + black, there are plenty of solutions) or build `__annotations__` dynamically (depends on usage: it won't be visible for type checkers like mypy, but will work for something that uses annotations at runtime). So the explanation of how it's used later is crucial here.

Comment: I think I will go for the codegen. Too difficult to figure out what is this used for, as the code that uses the class is not mine and I can't read it. Thanks for the suggestion!